# meaning of "single space" in c# variable declaration?

Tags: c#

Utter noob question on C# - in the code below, what does the line

```
UIWindow window;
```

mean exactly and what is its relationship to the line

```
window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
```

Is "UIWindow window" some kind of variable declaration?

```
public partial class AppDelegate : UIApplicationDelegate
{
    UIWindow window;
    HelloWorld_iPhoneViewController viewController;

    /// <summary>
    /// This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
    /// method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
    /// visible.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// You have 5 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
    /// </remarks>
    public override bool FinishedLaunching (UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        // create a new window instance based on the screen size
        window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);


        viewController = new HelloWorld_iPhoneViewController ("HelloWorld_iPhoneViewController", null);
        window.RootViewController = viewController;
        window.MakeKeyAndVisible ();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really don't know this, you are in for a long day.  It would be best to do some basic self-education before trying to write (or understand) C# code.

Comment: I agree with Steve - the [C# info page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) contains learning references.

Comment: @SteveTownsend well it's gonna be a long day anyhow :) I'm coming from javascript where everything is "var window" etc.

Comment: @Petrov That's nice. C# is not JavaScript (and I would no more expect a C#-only developer to somehow "magically" know about JavaScript scoping rules). See above.

Comment: @pst JavaScript has scoping rules?  I thought it just did whatever it felt like and you had to just hope for the best...

Comment: @Petrov C# is very similar to Java (NOT Javascript).

Comment: @EtherDragon Lol, no. C# 1.0 *was* very similar to Java pick-a-version. C# 3.0+ is a very much nicer beast. Okay, there are the strong-static-nominative-typing/single-dispatch/single-inheritance/class-instance similarities .. but to say C# is "*very* similar" to Java does a disservice to modern C#!

Comment: @pst Only because they added LINQ, generics, and XAML (to name a couple). But the core language concepts are still nearly identical to Java. The rest is the triumph of the framework more than changes to the actual language. An "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error in Java means precicely the same thing as in C# ;-b... Wait 'til Petrov runs into his first null reference error.

Comment: @EtherDragon Aye, point - that is a perpetuated "problem" of C# taking after Java too much =^_^= Although it's still quite frequent to run into `undefined.x` in JavaScript, so that'd be a relatively accepted surprise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line of code declares a variable named `window` of the type `UIWindow` (the value of which is initially null):

```
UWindow window;
```

And this line assigns a value to the `window` variable:

```
window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
```

Comment: Variables in C# are case-sensitive - Window and window are not the same. And your example is wrong in that light.

Comment: A variable like that which is declared inside a `class` or `struct` but not inside any method, is actually called a **field**. Also note that a field is always `private` if no access modifyer (like `internal` or `public`) is given. Here `private` means that the field can only be used from inside the `class` (`struct`) in question. The "word" before the space is a _type_, specifically the (strong) compile-time type of the field. The "word" after the space is an _identifyer_ and gives the name of the field.

Answer (score 2):

```
UIWindow window;
```

This creates a new variable of type UIWindow

```
window = new UIWindow (UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
```

This initializes the window varible, it's null before this line is invoked.